# Why does mapping over a Scala enumeration's ValueSet not change the type of the values?

Tags: scala, enumeration

I found some puzzling behavior in Scala's ValueSet. With an enum like this,

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration{
    val V1 = new MyEnum
    val V2 = new MyEnum
    class MyEnum extends Val
    implicit def convertValue(v: Value): MyEnum = v.asInstanceOf[MyEnum]
}
```

Mapping `MyEnum.values` from Value to MyEnum produces another ValueSet, which when converted to an array does not retain the mapped type.

```
val naiveMappedValues = MyEnum.values.map(
    implicitly[MyEnum.Value => MyEnum.MyEnum]).toArray
// REPL prints: naiveMappedValues: Array[MyEnum.Value] = Array(V1, V2)
```

If `MyEnum.values` is first converted to a list, then the type of the final array is correct.

```
val mappedValues = MyEnum.values.toList.map(
    implicitly[MyEnum.Value => MyEnum.MyEnum]).toArray
// REPL prints: mappedValues: Array[MyEnum.MyEnum] = Array(V1, V2)
```

Why does this happen? Why is it necessary to first convert the ValueSet to a List before mapping the values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MyEnum.values` returns an `Enumeration.ValueSet`. `ValueSet` subtypes `Set[Value]`. When you do the `map` on the `ValueSet`, it tries to return a new `ValueSet` to you, which it can do as long as the new elements are a subtype of `Value`. However, a `ValueSet` is always a `Set[Value]`, so the down-cast done inside your map is undone when the elements are up-cast back to `Value`. `List`, on the other hand, has a type parameter, so you can map a `List[Value]` to a `List[MyEnum]`.

All of this magic is controlled by the `CanBuildFrom` that `map` takes. If you use `collection.breakOut` you can force `map` to build any type you want:

```
val fastMappedValues: Array[MyEnum.MyEnum] = MyEnum.values.map(
    implicitly[MyEnum.Value => MyEnum.MyEnum])(collection.breakOut)
```

Comment: In your example you intended to show that `toList` isn't necessary.

Comment: @som-snytt Oops. Editted.